# POWERAPPS: Include query after executing the code

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps, power-automate

how can I include a query in the code below when the flow has been successfully executed?

A query like this:

`Notify("Dateien erfolgreich hochgeladen", NotificationType.Success)`

This is the code:

`If( IsBlank(barcode.Text);         Notify("Fill in the field"; NotificationType.Warning); ForAll(ImageCollection;'ThisIsTheFlow'.Run(barcode.Text;{file:{contentBytes:Value;name:Name}}));;  ForAll(photos.Attachments;'ThisIsTheFlow'.Run(barcode.Text;{file:{contentBytes:Value;name:Name}}));;  Reset(barcode);;  Reset(barcodeScanner);;  SetFocus(barcode);; Reset(photos);;  Clear(ImageCollection);;  );;`